# Change font in beamer with TexLive

Tags: beamer, fonts, texlive

TexLive includes many of the fonts in the catalogue, making it very easy to use alternative fonts in articles, reports or books. For instance, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß}
}
\newcommand{\testtext}{The
    quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
ä Ä ß }
\usepackage{electrum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{A Document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\testtext
\end{document}
```

Produces this output:

[image]

But a similar set up with a beamer type of document has no effect. For instance, this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß}
}
\newcommand{\testtext}{The
    quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
ä Ä ß }
\usepackage{electrum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A sample frame}
    \testtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

How can I use a font like ElectrumADF in a beamer type of document with TexLive?

Comment: As the Electrum font is a serif font, add `\usefonttheme{serif}` in your preamble.

Comment: @Paul Gaborit, that was it, would you like to file an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Electrum font is a *serif* font, add `\usefonttheme{serif}` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß}
}
\newcommand{\testtext}{The
    quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
ä Ä ß }
\usepackage{electrum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A sample frame}
    \testtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]